# Seemingly successful start of a process does not show up in a "ps" command

Tags: delayed-job

```
rails@george:/srv/fsg_distro$ /usr/bin/env HOME=/home/rails RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/ruby /srv/fsg_distro/current/script/delayed_job start
delayed_job: process with pid 23622 started.
rails@george:/srv/fsg_distro$ ps -ef | grep 23622
rails@george:/srv/fsg_distro$
```

Is ps lying to me?  Probably not.  I would imagine the delayed job script is starting and stopping right away.  Does anyone know of a good way to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the exit status of env?

```
0   if no COMMAND is specified and the environment is output
1   if `env' itself fails
126 if COMMAND is found but cannot be invoked
127 if COMMAND cannot be found
the exit status of COMMAND otherwise
```